# remove pagination in admin content page

Tags: views, paging

I cloned /admin/content (via the Views module). The clone uses a different URL (e.g. /admin/content/clone) and doesn't use any pagination.

In the view, I've set the pagination to *Display all items*; then, I hit save.  When I navigate to /admin/content/clone, it still shows the pagination. I've already cleared the cache.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

This is the exported view.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'clone_of_admin_view_nodes';
$view->description = 'Find and manage content.';
$view->tag = 'admin';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Clone of Admin View: Nodes';
$view->core = 0;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Defaults */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'etaewtaweta';
$handler->display->display_options['css_class'] = 'admin-views-view';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'menu';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['distinct'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['autosubmit'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'views_bulk_operations' => 'views_bulk_operations',
  'type' => 'type',
  'title' => 'title',
  'timestamp' => 'timestamp',
  'title_1' => 'title_1',
  'title_2' => 'title_2',
  'field_content_owner' => 'field_content_owner',
  'status' => 'status',
  'changed' => 'changed',
  'edit_node' => 'edit_node',
  'delete_node' => 'delete_node',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'views_bulk_operations' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'type' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'timestamp' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'title_1' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'title_2' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_content_owner' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'status' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'changed' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'edit_node' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'delete_node' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* No results behavior: Global: Unfiltered text */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area_text_custom']['id'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area_text_custom']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area_text_custom']['field'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area_text_custom']['empty'] = TRUE;
/* Relationship: Content: Author */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Relationship: Content: Taxonomy terms on node */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['id'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['field'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['vocabularies'] = array(
  'forums' => 0,
  'tags' => 0,
);
/* Relationship: Book: Top level book */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['bid']['id'] = 'bid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['bid']['table'] = 'book';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['bid']['field'] = 'bid';
/* Relationship: Book: Parent */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'book_parent';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
/* Field: Bulk operations: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'action::node_assign_owner_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Change author',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_delete_item' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Delete',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_delete_revision' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_script_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_make_sticky_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Stick',
  ),
  'action::node_make_unsticky_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Unstick',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_modify_action' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Change content owner(s)',
    'settings' => array(
      'show_all_tokens' => 0,
      'display_values' => array(
        'book::field_content_owner' => 'book::field_content_owner',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_move_to_book_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_argument_selector_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
    'settings' => array(
      'url' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'action::node_promote_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Promote to front page',
  ),
  'action::node_publish_action' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Publish',
  ),
  'action::node_unpromote_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Demote from front page',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_remove_from_book_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_save_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::system_send_email_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_unpublish_action' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 1,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Unpublish',
  ),
  'action::node_unpublish_by_keyword_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::pathauto_node_update_action' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
);
/* Field: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['field'] = 'type';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
/* Field: Content: Has new content */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'history';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['id'] = 'title_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['relationship'] = 'bid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['label'] = 'Book';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_2']['id'] = 'title_2';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_2']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_2']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_2']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_2']['label'] = 'Parent';
/* Field: Content: Content Owner(s) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_content_owner']['id'] = 'field_content_owner';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_content_owner']['table'] = 'field_data_field_content_owner';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_content_owner']['field'] = 'field_content_owner';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_content_owner']['type'] = 'taxonomy_term_reference_plain';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_content_owner']['delta_offset'] = '0';
/* Field: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['not'] = 0;
/* Field: Content: Updated date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['id'] = 'changed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['field'] = 'changed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['label'] = 'Updated';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['date_format'] = 'short';
/* Field: Content: Edit link */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_node']['id'] = 'edit_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_node']['table'] = 'views_entity_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_node']['field'] = 'edit_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['edit_node']['label'] = 'Operations';
/* Field: Content: Delete link */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_node']['id'] = 'delete_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_node']['table'] = 'views_entity_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_node']['field'] = 'delete_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['delete_node']['label'] = '';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'book' => 'book',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'type_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['label'] = 'Type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['operator'] = 'type_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['identifier'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['label'] = 'Title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['identifier'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['id'] = 'title_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['relationship'] = 'bid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['value'] = 'Demo';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'title_1_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['expose']['label'] = 'Book';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['expose']['operator'] = 'title_1_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['expose']['identifier'] = 'title_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['is_grouped'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['group_info']['label'] = 'Book';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['group_info']['identifier'] = 'book';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['group_info']['remember'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['group_info']['group_items'] = array(
  1 => array(
    'title' => 'Products and Investments',
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => 'Products & Investments',
  ),
  2 => array(
    'title' => 'Systems and Technology',
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => 'Systems and Technology',
  ),
  3 => array(
    'title' => 'Ops and Admin',
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => 'Ops & Admin',
  ),
  4 => array(
    'title' => 'Compliance',
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => 'Compliance',
  ),
  5 => array(
    'title' => 'Dept and Services',
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => 'Dept & Services',
  ),
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['id'] = 'title_2';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'title_2_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['expose']['label'] = 'Parent';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['expose']['operator'] = 'title_2_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['expose']['identifier'] = 'parent';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_2']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Content Owner(s) (field_content_owner) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['id'] = 'field_content_owner_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_content_owner';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['field'] = 'field_content_owner_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_content_owner_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['expose']['label'] = 'Content Owner';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_content_owner_tid_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['expose']['identifier'] = 'content_owner';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['type'] = 'select';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['vocabulary'] = 'content_owners';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_content_owner_tid']['hierarchy'] = 1;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 'All';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator_id'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['label'] = 'Published';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['identifier'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
);

/* Display: System */
$handler = $view->new_display('system', 'System', 'system_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['hide_admin_links'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['access'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'admin/list';

/* Display: System 2 */
$handler = $view->new_display('system', 'System 2', 'system_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['access'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'admin/blah4';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I get it: the problem is this is using the System display, not the regular Page one. You can see it in the Views list:

> **Administration: Nodes**
>   Display: *System*
>   In code
>   Type: Content

What you should do is just create a regular 'page' display with all the settings you want to use.

If you just want to change the pagination and not have to re-create the whole view just go on and edit the main one!

BTW there was a guy with a similar problem on the issues list from the Administration Views module:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2539256